# Switch between html div class using EventListener JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, addeventlistener

So I have a simple HTML page with 5 buttons and 5 sections in it. Each time I 'click' one of these button, a JavaScript function switch the active section using an EventListener.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');

function pageTransition() {
  //Button click active class
  for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
    sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
      currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
      this.className += 'active-btn';
    })
  }

  //sections Active class
  allSections.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;
    if (id) {
      //remove selected from the other btns
      sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove('active')
      })
      e.target.classList.add('active')

      //hide other sections
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.classList.remove('active')
      })

      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.classList.add('active');
    }
  })
}

pageTransition()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body class="main-content">
  <header class="section sec1 header active" id="home">

  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="section sec2 about" id="about"></section>
    <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id="portfolio"></section>
    <section class="section sec4 blogs" id="blogs"></section>
    <section class="section sec5 contact" id="contact"></section>
  </main>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id="home">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-2 " data-id="about">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-3 " data-id="portfolio">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-4 " data-id="blogs">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="control control-5 " data-id="contact">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope-open"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that my section active class is not switching between each of the section when I click the corresponding button.

Comment: I checked your code and it's not working, so please add CSS too and put it in a snippet and make sure it's working so we can see what's going on then edit it.

Comment: Use `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()` to add and remove classes from elements, rather than string operations on `.className`

Comment: If you're only going to use the `[0]` element returned by `querySelectorAll()`, just use `querySelector()` to get the first match.